# Expectation with transformed random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

The expected value of a function $f$ of a random variable $x\in R^n$ is defined as 
$E_x[f(x)]=\int p(x)f(x)dx$ where $p()$ is the pdf of $x$.

Assume a function $h: R^m \rightarrow R$. Let $z=Mx$, where $M$ is a constant matrix $m\times n$. Is it true that $E_z[h(z)]=E_x[h(Mx)]$? In other words, does the "Law of the Unconscious Statistician" holds for compositions of possibly non-linear functions of a random variable/vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Z=\mathbf{M}X$ (where I use upper case symbols for random variables $Z$ and $X$), the random variable $h(Z)$ has the same distribution as the random variable $h(\mathbf{M}X)$ and hence their expectations are identical$$\mathbb{E}_Z[h(Z)]=\mathbb{E}_X[h(\mathbf{M}X)]$$